# Apache2 hosted site gives 400 Bad Request when browsing to http://www.example.org, but works perfectly on http://example.org

Tags: dns, apache2, virtualhost, http-code-400

So i've got a website hosted at example.com and I want it to work with www.example.com.

I've got a CNAME entry in my DNS for www pointing to example.com.

My virtual host config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin example.email@gmail.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/example/example/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/example/example/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

         Alias /media /home/ubuntu/example/example/media
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/example/example/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/example/example/example>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/example/example/example/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app  python-path=/home/ubuntu/example/example python-home=/home/ubuntu/example/example/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure what's wrong because to me it looks like everything is configured correctly.

Any tips?

Comment: "400 Bad Gateway" - Do you mean "Bad Request"? ("Bad Gateway" is 502)? FWIW, what you've posted _looks_ OK to me. Could your Django app be triggering this response?

Comment: Sorry yes you're right. It's a Bad Request error.
I'd not considered it being a Django issue to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to DocRobot, it ended up being a Django issue.

FWIW, the settings in a Django project have an allowed hosts sections. I'd only entered the hostname of the hosting server, example.com, where as it should have also added www.example.com.